# How to show one cols on mobile but three cols on desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to show three columns on desktop and one column on mobile. How can I do this? The div has to be responsive. Thanks!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-1">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm col-sm-offset-0 0 col-xs-1">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm col-xs-1">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The downvote is probably because Bootstrap documentation is quite clear, and it's not apparent why you weren't able to achieve your goal. Also, "responsive" isn't a specific behavior but a general reference to flexibility for various situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with all the offset and other classes, but this is about as simple a situation as they come. You want full-width columns (not *one* column, but three stacked columns) on mobile and 1/3 (4/12) width columns above some breakpoint.

The `col-12` class takes 12 of 12 width units starting at the smallest screen sizes, and `col-lg-4` takes 4 of 12 width units starting at 992px. Per Bootstrap's "mobile first" convention, classes should be listed smallest to largest.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use media queries. Media queries are used to apply some CSS properties if specific condition is true.

Add id (or a unique class) to all three col divs. I used id="colX" for example:

```html
<div id="col1">
  <img src = "/static/assets/howitworks3.png"/>
  <p> Test </p>
</div>
<div id="col2">
  <img src = "/static/assets/howitworks3.png" />
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
<div id="col3">
  <img src ="/static/assets/howitworks3.png" />
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Add viewport to the `<head>` of your html file like this:

```css
<head>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1'/>
  <!-- Other meta tags ... --> 
</head>
```

And add this css property to your styles:

```css
@media (max-width: 599px) {#col2, #col3 { display: none; }}
```

Comment: Maybe that dislike is because you prefer to use bootstrap instead

Comment: Probably. Plus I don't think they wanted to _hide_ columns, but stack them. Also, don't use IDs for CSS unless necessary. Code should be reusable whenever possible. This is a perfect case for a shared class.

Comment: Yes but I told about media queries because this was a plain HTML example. I'm using vue anyway.